# Automatically joining the tables using the foreign keys in SQL server, pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, pyodbc

I access a database of SQL server using python. The database has around 200 tables, and it contains foreign keys between the tables.

I want to join the tables automatically using the foreign keys that are in the database, since doing it by hand is very tedious.

How can I create pandas dataframes of all the maximal possible joins of tables using the given foreign keys?

With pyodbc, I can successfully get each specific table after creating a connection with this line of code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("...")
```

Comment: Itś unclear what you're asking for

Comment: @tuergeist The database contains the tables and the foreign keys between them, which is all one needs for computing the join between every two tables having a foreign key between them. I want to repeatedly join all the tables as long as I can to create few big tables.

Comment: It's still unclear, whether this is a python or a database question

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard feature of SQL. You will have to query the system schema tables for the relationships & then build the queries yourself, probably using left joins.
I'm currently trying something similar, here's the SQL I'm using to get the relationships from SQL Server.

```
with fKC as
(
    select
            sfkc.constraint_object_id
            ,(select name from sys.objects as o where o.object_id=sfkc.constraint_object_id) as constraint_object_name
            ,sfkc.parent_object_id
            ,(select name from sys.objects as o where o.object_id=sfkc.parent_object_id) as parent_object_name
            ,sfkc.parent_column_id
            ,(select name from sys.columns as c where ((c.object_id=sfkc.parent_object_id)and(c.column_id=sfkc.parent_column_id))) as parent_column_name
            ,sfkc.referenced_object_id
            ,(select name from sys.objects as o where o.object_id=sfkc.referenced_object_id) as referenced_object_name
            ,sfkc.referenced_column_id
            ,(select name from sys.columns as c where ((c.object_id=sfkc.referenced_object_id)and(c.column_id=sfkc.referenced_column_id))) as referenced_column_name
    from sys.foreign_key_columns as sfkc
    where (sfkc.parent_object_id!=sfkc.referenced_object_id)
)

select *
from fKC
order by fKC.parent_object_name, fKC.referenced_object_name;
```